# Transpose Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to transpose data in one sheet as below using python:: AS IS

[image]

To be

[image]

when i try to use the below code , it is giving me the output as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
dfs = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None,header=None)
tester=dfs['data'].values.tolist()
keys = list(zip(*tester))[0]
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
keysu= [x for x in keys if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
values = list(zip(*tester))[1]
a = np.array(values).reshape(int(len(values)/len(keysu)),len(keysu))
list1=[keysu]
for i in a:
 list1.append(list(i))
 df=pd.DataFrame(list1)
 df.to_excel('test1.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to do `pivot`, not `transpose`.

Try: `df.pivot(index='Hierarchy', columns='Fiscal_Mo', values='Amount').fillna('')`.

The final `fillna('')` is required to replace `NaN` values for non-existing
combinations of `Fiscal_Mo` and `Hierarchy`, e.g. `201802` / `A`.

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Fiscal_Mo': ['201801', '201802', '201803', '201801'],
    'Hierarchy': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B'], 'Amount': [ 100, 20, 300, 400 ] } )
df.pivot(index='Hierarchy', columns='Fiscal_Mo',values='Amount').fillna('')
```

A remark concerning your comment: It contains `hierarchy` written with
**lower case** `h`. Maybe this is the source of your problem?

### Edit

Maybe `Hierarchy` is the index of your DataFrame.

In this case, the index of `pivot` table is to bo created just from the
index of the source DataFrame, so `index` parameter should be omitted.

The corresponding code to create the DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.Index(data=['A', 'B', 'C', 'B'], name='Hierarchy')
df = pd.DataFrame( data={'Fiscal_Mo': ['201801', '201802', '201803', '201801'],
    'Amount': [ 100, 20, 300, 400 ] }, index=ind)
```

and the command to create the `pivot` table is:

```
df.pivot(columns='Fiscal_Mo', values='Amount').fillna('')
```

### Edit 2

**Investigation concerning `header=None`**

The first attempt: I executed:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Report.xlsx', sheet_name='Report', header=None)
```

and printed the `df`, the result was:

```
           0          1       2
0  Fiscal_Mo  Hierarchy  Amount
1     201801          A     100
2     201802          B      20
3     201803          C     300
4     201801          B     400
```

As you can see:

1. Column names in the DataFrame are **consecutive numbers** (wrong).
2. Column names from the source file (*Fiscal_Mo*, *Hierarchy*, *Amount*)
   are values of the **first row** (wrong).

Here, any attempt to call any Pandas function and passing "textual"
column names will fail.

The second attempt: I executed:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Report.xlsx', sheet_name='Report')
```

Note that this time there is no `header` parameter, so the function
assumes `header=0` - read column names from row 0 (initial).

When I printed the `df`, the result was:

```
   Fiscal_Mo Hierarchy  Amount
0     201801         A     100
1     201802         B      20
2     201803         C     300
3     201801         B     400
```

As you can see:

1. Column names in the DataFrame are taken from row number 0 (OK).
2. Data rows are taken from "further" rows (OK).

Now you can call e.g.:

```
df.pivot(index='Hierarchy', columns='Fiscal_Mo', values='Amount').fillna('')
```

without any errors.

Note that:

1. Parameter values must **exactly** match respective column names
   (lower / upper case letters).
2. I called `df.pivot(...)` not `pd.pivot(df, ...)`. Apparently you failed
   to read carefully my instructions and copy **all** parameters to your code.

Conclusion: Delete `header=None` from `read_excel` call and your
program should work.

Comment: Thanks Valdi for the answer , but i am getting below error while trying to use code  return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: 'hierarchy'

Comment: i tried with lowercase - "h" as well, i am trying to read excel file and trying to pivot the data in the sheet using --                                                                  df = pd.read_excel('Report_test1_ 111818_15_32_27.xlsx', sheet_name="test",header=None)
d = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["hierarchy"])

Comment: Note that in the example code I have written *index='Hierarchy'* (without square parentheses) and there is also *columns='Fiscal_No'*.

Comment: Apparently the first row contains just column names. Why did you write *header=None*? In such case the first row (column names) is actually the first data row and column names are consecutive numbers. I think, this is not what you want. To check this detail, add *print(df)* to your code.

Comment: Thanks Valdi .. Scenario 2 worked perfectly.. but i have a doubt here on how to do dynamic changing index where as columns and values column remain constant